# Spring Frameworks Shell - Adding Colour

Tags: java, spring, shell, spring-shell

I am currently making a app that acts as a shell using the spring framework. In the documentation it says as its based of roo it supports colour on both unix and windows platforms (via jansi) but does not say how to use it. Having `@|red text|@` does not seem to work and google isnt being much of a help as i either come accross random documentation that doesnt help or to use threads that say to use the ASCI referances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jansi` directly in your shell command implementation. 
Something like the following:

```
@CliCommand("hello")
public String hello(@CliOption(key="who") String who) {
    return Ansi.ansi().render("@|red Hello|@ " + who);
}
```

Comment: Ah awesome, what about for the banner, just do the same thing as above and not use the string builder?